# Accurate date formate and compare date in iphone dev?

Tags: iphone

I am new in iphone, i want to change string into accurate date-formate which i couldn't done this for last 2 hrs. I have string like(17:30 18 Oct) and want to convert this in accurate formate  and also compare this date to tomorrow if this in tomorrow then display just 18 Oct and if it on today just display time 17:30, any help please.

Comment: See here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: See this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496383/nsdateformatter-iphone

Answer (score 3):

NSString to NSDate conversion

```
    NSString *dateString = @"6:30 18 Oct";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm dd/MMM"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    [dateFormatter release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mma dd/MMM"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
    NSLog(@"date: %@", dateString);
    [dateFormat release];
```

Comment: If its worked for you accept it as an answer so that it will not appear in unanswered questions

Comment: you converted NDDate to NSString but i need reverse of that, NSString to NSDate.?