# Accurate Date formate for hours time and date month in iphone?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accurate date formate and compare date in iphone dev?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803372/accurate-date-formate-and-compare-date-in-iphone-dev)

I am new in i phone. Can any one tell what will be accurate date-formate for (6:30 18 Oct) string to NS Date.